# `git add --interactive` and `git commit filename` confusion

Tags: git, commit, revision-control

Committing only parts of your edits is possible by using either `git add --interactive` or `git commit filename`.
However when combining both methods the results are unexpected.

For example you "stage" one out of four hunks in `file1` (among other staging in different files).
Then you want to commit only those changes staged for `file1`, using `git commit file1` (`git commit` would only commit the staged changes of all files).

Unfortunately the result is that *all* changes made to `file1` are committed.

Is this a bug, and if not:
Is there a way to commit only the staged changes of a specific file?

Comment: Never tried similar stuff but it sounds to me that you shouldn't (need to) have `file` after `commit` if you rely on `add` (to "partially stage"). It sounds natural to me if git assume you want to commit *all* (staged and unstaged) changes you made to that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are a little bit confused:

[`git add --interactive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt---interactive) -- Interactive way to stage files.

[`git commit file`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt-ltpathspecgt82308203) -- commit **only** file. Staged changes ignored during this commit.

[`git add -p file`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt---patch) -- partially stage changes of file

Comment: Well, my assumption was that `git commit file` would only commit the staged changes (that is the intersection of the staged changes and the file's changes). Or is `git commit file` identical to `git add file; git commit file`?

Comment: Yes `git commit file` is identical to `git add file; git commit file`. But you should understand that `git commit file`  completely disregards stage, so `git add file` is redundant in this case. @U.Windl

Comment: I wasn't aware that I can `git commit file` without having to add (stage) it before.